How to format date if it can be null spring
I’ve got a form on thymeleaf, that contains many type=date inputs. I need to get those dates on PostMapping. Sometimes it came with null value and compiler gives error

“required request parameter ‘date_smth’ for method parameter type Date
is present but converted to null”

For dates I’m using Java.util.Date
Now I’m trying to use formatter in RequestParam
@RequestParam(“date_smth_form”) @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date_smth

In my Entity I didn’t apply any configuration for this date columns, just:
Private Date date_smth

If u want to ask me, why u need formatter at all? I want my date to be yyyy.MM.dd format always, without any time data or utc data, just date.

You should be using java.time.LocalDate probably

@g00se, can it be null while formatting?

@Sergei just do a null check before formatting. "Date is present but converted to null" what do you mean by that? It should contain a value, but it doesn't?

I was actually making a separate point - that java.util.Date should no longer be used. It won't help with the 'null issue' but will probably help with the formatting issue

How a date is formatted is display logic not something you should be doing while binding. Next to that you shouldn't be using the old java.util.Data but rather the java.time.LocalDate class, which as the name implies is already a date only. Dates send through the date type are already send as ISO formatted dates, how it is being displayed depends on the locale of the browser.

@g00se thanks for your advice, it solves my problems, but it took a lot of time to process)

Well done for moving forward. As far as data strategy is concerned though, don't forget that Local in LocalDate means what it says

Thank to you all (  ) , using of LocalDate solve all my problems, but also want to add that I use @Nullable to my LocalDate variables on @PostMapping in @RequestParam. Before, I don’t want to use LocalDate, because someone, who writes code before me already use Java.sql.Date everywhere, in all repositories, in all entities, in all services, in all controllers. But I gathered my strength and rewrote everything under localDate.
Also, for me, I needed to convert LocalDate values to String on @GetMapping, don’t know, if it’s ok or not, but it’s works fine.
